# Why reduced mass in Central force field moving under the action of internal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I did the derivation of equivalent one body problem where we get,

$$\mu\frac{\text{d}^2r}{\text{d}t^2} = F_{\text{internal}}$$

But I don't understand even when internal force between two bodies are equal and opposite (according to Newton's third law), then those two internal force gets cancel out and contributes in the motion of the reduced mass $\mu$?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can derive for yourself. The key is to start from applying Newton's laws to the two bodies, labeled with positions $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$, separately. Then you change your coordinate system to the center of mass and relative coordinates:
\begin{align}
   \vec{R} &= \frac{m_1\vec{r}_1 + m_2 \vec{r}_2}{m_1 + m_2},\text{ and} \\
   \vec{r} & = \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \Rightarrow \\
   \vec{r}_1 & = \vec{R} + \frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}\vec{r},\text{ and}\\
   \vec{r}_2 &= \vec{R} - \frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}\vec{r}.
\end{align}
If you handle all of the algebra and calculus correctly you'll find that your equations of motion become
\begin{align}
   (m_1 + m_2) \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} \vec{R} & = \sum_{\mathrm{all}}\vec{F}_{\mathrm{external}} \\
   \left(\frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{1}{m_2}\right)^{-1} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} \vec{r} & = \vec{F}_{\text{2 on 1}} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{on 1}} \vec{F}_{\text{external}} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{on 2}} \vec{F}_{\text{external}}.
\end{align}

The point being that the internal forces cannot affect the center of mass $\vec{R}$, but they can affect the shape of the system $\vec{r}$.

Warning: I just did this on the fly, so there might have made some sign or other errors. Check for yourself!